Sending at commands to sim7600 and not receiving a response on Raspberry Pi Zero
I have been searching for a few days but I have not found any results.
I have a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W and a sim7600 hat and I want to send at commands to it using a program I wrote.
When I use minicom as sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB2, the at command response is sent from sim7600 to Raspberry Pi just fine.
But when I run my program, I do not receive any response from sim7600 when sending at commands. I know that the at commands are working properly in my program because if I enter the AT+CRESET command in my program, the module is reset and then if I close my program and immediately run the program again, I can see the response to the at commands I send but again after a few seconds there is no response.
this is my c# code:
class Program
{
    static SerialPort portUSB;

    static void Main()
    {
        
        Console.Write("select Port:");
        string port = Console.ReadLine();
        portUSB = new SerialPort(port, 115200);
        

            Console.WriteLine("connecting to ttyUSB2 ...");
            portUSB.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            portUSB.DtrEnable = true;
            portUSB.RtsEnable = true;
            portUSB.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            portUSB.WriteTimeout = 2000;
            
            portUSB.DataReceived += PortUSB_DataReceived;
            portUSB.Open();


        Console.WriteLine("Write and Enter to send Message and press ctrl+c to exit");


        while (true)
        {

            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                string message = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                {
                    SendMessage(message);
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    private static void PortUSB_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        sp.DiscardInBuffer();
        sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
        Console.Write(indata);
    }

    static void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            if (portUSB.IsOpen)
            {
                portUSB.Write(message + "\r\n");

                Console.WriteLine("Command Sent " + message);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ttyUSB2 Not open!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

    }
}

https://i.sstatic.net/gwzRpx1I.png
1- First, to ensure the correct connection, I used minicom and opened the ttyUSB2 port and sent at commands and received responses.
2- I connected the sim7600 to the windows system using a micro usb cable and ran the program I had written on it (on COM7). The commands were sent well and the responses were received.
3- I connected the sim7600 hat to the Raspberry Zero and ran my program (/dev/ttyUSB2). The at commands were sent but no response was received.

If you search for "SerialPort DataReceived" you'll find a lot of similar questions. The usage of that function is a bit tricky, and I would generally recommend not to use that callback but write the receiver thread on your own. In either case, the DiscradInBuffer and DiscardOutBuffer calls are certainly wrong, as they drop all remaining input or output that might still be underway.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79252620/10024425

I also tested the code without DiscardInBuffer and DiscardOutBuffer but the result was the same.
